# Excluding files in assembly from being moled

Tags: moles, pex

I am using moles to generate mock classes for the legacy code my team uses. Is it possible to exclude certain classes in the assembly from being moled? I am getting a lot of errors for some autogenerated classes we have in the legacy code which I want to exclude from being moled.

Answer (score 4):

To include and exclude types from stub/mole generation, you need to modify the .moles file for your assembly. Although the section "Type Filtering" of the reference manual describes only the `StubGeneration` element, there is also the `MoleGeneration` element which works similarly but manages mole generation.

To exclude a type from stub and mole generation specify the type name in a `Remove` element so that the .moles file for your assembly looks like this:

```
<Moles xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/moles/2010/" Diagnostic="true">
    <Assembly Name="your_assembly" />
    <StubGeneration>
        <Types>
            <Remove FullName="Your.Type.Full.Name!" />
        </Types>
    </StubGeneration>
    <MoleGeneration>
        <Types>
            <Remove FullName="Your.Type.Full.Name!" />
        </Types>
    </MoleGeneration>
</Moles>
```

Here's how to enable stub and mole generation only for one class `Your.Type.Full.Name`:

```
<Moles xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/moles/2010/" Diagnostic="true">
    <Assembly Name="your_assembly" />
    <StubGeneration>
        <Types>
            <Clear />
            <Add FullName="Your.Type.Full.Name!" />
        </Types>
    </StubGeneration>
    <MoleGeneration>
        <Types>
            <Clear />
            <Add FullName="Your.Type.Full.Name!" />
        </Types>
    </MoleGeneration>
</Moles>
```